# Setup requires the computer to be restarted before visual studio can run

Tags: visual-studio-2019

My visual studio is working fine until past midnight and suddenly crashed this morning with the below error.

[image]

Comment: VS2022 may have the same problem from time to time.

Answer (score 20):

1. Press Windows (Button on your keyboard)+ R (to open up the RUN application)
2. Type  "regedit" (this will open up an application that will allow you to edit the Registry )
3. If you are using a 64bit Visual Studio copy and paste the path below in the Registry Editor path finder

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\Reboot

4. Before you do anything, backup the Registry by going to File then Export
5. After you backup the registry, DELETE found in Reboot under Setup.

Comment: I avoided deleting the key by changing any DWORD value in that registry section to 0 which seems to have done the trick

Comment: @matt
Yours is a better, safer solution. For it to work for me I had to run regedit as admin.

Comment: I also just changed the value to 0 and this worked with V2022.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer very hard way so try to help others here. Simply search "Visual Studio Installer" then you will see vs2019 and click on Restart that's it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. After another restart it still demanded I restart the computer.